# Javascript postMessage between cross domain tabs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement `PostMessage` across popup and window. `postMessage` works if the popup code is in `iframe` but not when the same page is opened in popup.

The parent code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var XD = function(){

    var interval_id,
    last_hash,
    cache_bust = 1,
    attached_callback,
    window = this;

    return {
        postMessage : function(message, target_url, target) {
            if (!target_url) {
                return;
            }
            target = target || parent;  // default to parent
            if (window['postMessage']) {
                // the browser supports window.postMessage, so call it with a targetOrigin
                // set appropriately, based on the target_url parameter.
                target['postMessage'](message, target_url.replace( /([^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+).*/, '$1'));
            } else if (target_url) {
                // the browser does not support window.postMessage, so use the window.location.hash fragment hack
                target.location = target_url.replace(/#.*$/, '') + '#' + (+new Date) + (cache_bust++) + '&' + message;
            }
        },
        receiveMessage : function(callback, source_origin) {
            // browser supports window.postMessage
            if (window['postMessage']) {
                // bind the callback to the actual event associated with window.postMessage
                if (callback) {
                  console.log(source_origin);
                    attached_callback = function(e) {
                      console.log(source_origin, e.origin);
                        if ((typeof source_origin === 'string' && e.origin !== source_origin)
                        || (Object.prototype.toString.call(source_origin) === "[object Function]" && source_origin(e.origin) === !1)) {
                             return !1;
                         }
                         callback(e);
                     };
                 }
                 if (window['addEventListener']) {
                     window[callback ? 'addEventListener' : 'removeEventListener']('message', attached_callback, !1);
                 } else {
                     window[callback ? 'attachEvent' : 'detachEvent']('onmessage', attached_callback);
                 }
             } else {
                 // a polling loop is started & callback is called whenever the location.hash changes
                 interval_id && clearInterval(interval_id);
                 interval_id = null;
                 if (callback) {
                     interval_id = setInterval(function() {
                         var hash = document.location.hash,
                         re = /^#?\d+&/;
                         if (hash !== last_hash && re.test(hash)) {
                             last_hash = hash;
                             callback({data: hash.replace(re, '')});
                         }
                     }, 100);
                 }
             }
         }
    };
}();



var opt = 'location=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,height=400,width=400';
var chld = window.open('http://secure.domain.dev/try1.html', 'chd', opt);


XD.receiveMessage(function (message) {
  console.log(secure.chatsock.dev)
}, 'http://secure.doain.dev');
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Popup code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var XD = function(){

    var interval_id,
    last_hash,
    cache_bust = 1,
    attached_callback,
    window = this;

    return {
        postMessage : function(message, target_url, target) {
            if (!target_url) {
                return;
            }
            target = target || parent;  // default to parent
            if (window['postMessage']) {
                // the browser supports window.postMessage, so call it with a targetOrigin
                // set appropriately, based on the target_url parameter.
                target['postMessage'](message, target_url.replace( /([^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+).*/, '$1'));
            } else if (target_url) {
                // the browser does not support window.postMessage, so use the window.location.hash fragment hack
                target.location = target_url.replace(/#.*$/, '') + '#' + (+new Date) + (cache_bust++) + '&' + message;
            }
        },
        receiveMessage : function(callback, source_origin) {
            // browser supports window.postMessage
            if (window['postMessage']) {
                // bind the callback to the actual event associated with window.postMessage
                if (callback) {
                    attached_callback = function(e) {
                        if ((typeof source_origin === 'string' && e.origin !== source_origin)
                        || (Object.prototype.toString.call(source_origin) === "[object Function]" && source_origin(e.origin) === !1)) {
                             return !1;
                         }
                         callback(e);
                     };
                 }
                 if (window['addEventListener']) {
                     window[callback ? 'addEventListener' : 'removeEventListener']('message', attached_callback, !1);
                 } else {
                     window[callback ? 'attachEvent' : 'detachEvent']('onmessage', attached_callback);
                 }
             } else {
                 // a polling loop is started & callback is called whenever the location.hash changes
                 interval_id && clearInterval(interval_id);
                 interval_id = null;
                 if (callback) {
                     interval_id = setInterval(function() {
                         var hash = document.location.hash,
                         re = /^#?\d+&/;
                         if (hash !== last_hash && re.test(hash)) {
                             last_hash = hash;
                             callback({data: hash.replace(re, '')});
                         }
                     }, 100);
                 }
             }
         }
    };
}();

setTimeout(function () {
    XD.postMessage('Test DaTa', 'http://localhost/test/test.html', window.parent);
}, 1000);

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? If this wont work, is there any work around for this across browsers?

Comment: I haven't tried `postMessage` with windows so far, but theoretically it should work. I'd say there is an error in your 2nd code, try using  `target = window.opener` instead of `target = target || parent`. The same goes for the first code: use the window reference returned by `open()`

Comment: @try-catch-finally Thanks, window.opener thing fixed it....